# representer theorem in kernel ridge regression for slightly modified loss function

Tags: optimization, kernel-trick

It is very well known that for a problem of the form

$$\min_f\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i -f(x_i))^2 + \lambda \|f\|^2_\mathcal{H}, \quad\lambda\ge0$$

for a $f$ in a RKHS $\mathcal{H}$ has a solution

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^nc_iK(x_i,x)\tag{1}$$

where $c$ solves the system of equations

$$(K+\lambda n \textbf{1})c = y\tag{2}$$

for the kernel $K$ of the RKHS $\mathcal{H}$. My question is can this be generalized to cases where we look at

$$\min_f\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \big(y_i - \beta_i^T\big[f(x_1);\cdots;f(x_m)\big]\big)^2 + \lambda \|f\|^2_\mathcal{H}$$

for given vectors $\beta_i$ and $\lambda >0$. I've found a general version of the representer theorem which covers this kind of form, too. I.e. the solution is still of the form $(1)$. However, is there also a generalization of $(2)$ in this case? A proof / reference would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you made a typo? Do you actually want the dimension of the domain of $f$ to be the same as the number of data points, and $x_i$ to be evaluated as the $i$'th coordinate? If so, this is very strange, since this would be a trivial problem.

Comment: @Hans I've edited my question. What I mean is, that compared to $(1)$ where $f$ for the pair $(x_i,y_i)$ only takes into account a single feature $x_i$, in $(2)$ I want to build a vector for all the vaules of features $x_i$

Comment: @math I think Hans is asking if you mean $x_i$ to have $p$ features, in which case you want $f$ to be a function retuning a $p$ vector, $\beta$ to be a $p$ vector, and you can write $$\min_f\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \beta_i^Tf(x_i))^2 + \lambda ||f||^2_{\mathcal{H}}\,.$$ Is this what you're interested in?

Comment: @Nate thanks for your comment. What I mean is, that $f$ is a scalar valued function. It takes a single argument from the feature space $X$. However in the loss function I use for each term $y_i - \beta_i^T[f(x_1),\dots,f(x_m)]$ always the set of ALL observed values of the features: $x_1,\dots,x_m$ and stack it into a vector. I hope this makes it clear

Comment: @Hans I slightly updated the question. Note that $[f(x_1),\dots,f(x_m)]$ does not depend on $i$. It is the vector of stacked values of $f$ evaluated at all given realizations of features $x_1,\dots,x_m$.

Comment: I have edited the answer to match your modified formulation. The argument remains essentially intact, except $\beta$ turns into a rectangular matrix from a square matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the domain of the functions of $\mathcal H$ is $X$. Let $k: X\times X\rightarrow \mathbf R$ be the reproducing kernel, which is symmetric and positive semidefinite. Define
$$L[f] := \sum_{i=1}^n \big(y_i -\beta_i^
T\vec f\big)^2 + \lambda \|f\|^2_\mathcal{H}, \quad\lambda\ge0$$
where $\vec f := \big[f(x_1),f(x_2),\cdots,f(x_m)\big]^T$ and $\beta_i$ is a column matrix. Let $M:=
\{1,2,\cdots,m\}$ and $N:=
\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.
(The factor $\frac1n$ in the original question formulation is absorbed into $\lambda$ so as to abbreviate the notations.)

$\forall f\in\mathcal H,$
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i k(\cdot,x_i)+v$$
for some $(c_i)_{i\in M}$ and some $(v\in\mathcal H) \perp \operatorname{span}(\{K(\cdot,x_i)|i\in M\})$ or $\langle v,k(\cdot,x_i)\rangle=0,\,\forall i\in M$. So for $\forall j\in M$
\begin{align}
f(x_j)&=\langle f,k(\cdot,x_j) \rangle \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i \langle k(\cdot,x_i),k(\cdot,x_j)\rangle +\langle v,k(\cdot,x_j)\rangle \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m c_i k(x_i,x_j),
\end{align}
and $f(x_j)$ is independent of $v$.
\begin{align}
\|f\|^2_{\mathcal H}&=\Big\langle \sum_{i=1}^m c_i k(\cdot,x_i), \sum_{j=1}^m c_i k(\cdot,x_j) \Big\rangle+\|v\|_\mathcal H^2 \\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^m c_i k(x_i,x_j) c_j+\|v\|^2_\mathcal H
\end{align}
since $v\perp$ span$(k(\cdot,x_i)|i\in M)$.

Therefore the $f$ that minimizes $L[f]$ should have $v=0$. We denote such $f$ by $f^*$, and
$$f^*:=\operatorname{arg min}_{f \in\mathcal H}L[f]=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i k(\cdot,x_i)$$
and
$$f^*(x_j)=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i k(x_j,x_i),\quad\forall i\in M,$$
or in the matrix form
$$\vec {f^*}=Kc$$
where $m\times m$ matrix $K$ has $(j,i)$'th entry $K_{j,i}:=k(x_j,x_i),\,\forall i,j \in M$ and $m\times 1$ matrix $c$ has entry $c_i,\,\forall i\in M$. Matrix $K$ is symmetric since the function $k(\cdot,\cdot)$ is symmetric.

Let the $n\times 1$ matrix $y:=[y_i]_{i\in N}$, and $n\times m$ matrix $\beta:= [\beta_i^T]_{i\in N}$ be the matrices constructed from stacking the components on the right hand side vertically.  Substituting $f=f^*$ into $L[f]$, we have
\begin{align}
L[f^*]&=(y-\beta Kc)^T(y-\beta Kc)+\lambda c^T Kc \\
&= c^T(K\beta^T\beta K+\lambda K)c-2y^T\beta K c +y^Ty.
\end{align}
Thus $L[f^*]$ minimizes at
$$0=\big(K\beta^T\beta K+\lambda K\big)c-K \beta^T y=Ku,$$
with
$$u:=(\beta^T\beta K+\lambda I)c-\beta^T y.$$
It is true iff $u$ is in the null space of $K$ or that $u$ is a zero eigenvector $K$. If matrix $K$ is positive definite, the left $K$'s on both sides of the equation cancels and we have
$$c= (\beta^T\beta K+\lambda I)^{-1}(\beta^Ty+u)$$
so long as $\lambda>0$ or $\beta$ is of full rank. If $K$ is positive definite, $u=0$.

---

*Remark:*

The [kernel function $k(⋅,⋅)$ is positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel). That however does not guarantee the positive definiteness of matrix $K$. For example, the $K$ resulting from $\vec x$ with duplicating $x_i$ is not positive definite. All distinct $x_i$'s would not guarantee that either.

$\{k(\cdot,x_i)\}_{i\in M}$ with $x_i$'s all distinct is not necessarily linearly independent. For example, the linear kernel $k(x,y)=x^Ty,\, \forall x,y\in R^p$ for some natural number $p$. $\{k(\cdot,x_i)\}_{i\in M}$ is linearly dependent when $\{x_i\}_{i\in M}$ is.

Comment: Thanks Hans, it is clear now. Just one last question. Usually the kernel matrix is just positive semi-definite, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sure we can delete the first two comments

Comment: I have one more question which troubles me. I've implemented the solution....but I get different results when I use $c_1= (\beta^T\beta K+\lambda I)^{-1}(\beta^Ty)$ and $c_2=(K\beta^T\beta K + \lambda K)^{-1}K\beta^Ty$. Tha means $c_1\neq c_2$ Why is that the case? I've checked the implementation very carefully, i.e. I doubt there is an error. I have a benchmark solution which is the result I get from $c_1$.

Comment: @math: I have stated in the original answer that $K$ needs to be positive-definite. Have you checked that (or the nonsingularity)? In numerical computation, you need to compute the ratio of the smallest over the largest eigenvalues of $K$. If that is very small and comparable to the computer floating number resolution, $K$ is effectively singular. I have added the general solution into the answer. But check the singularity of $K$ first before worrying about the degeneracy.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience. So I've implemented it in python. As it seems numpy is able to do a Cholesky decomposition for K as well as it says that all eigenvalues are positive. So that $K$ should be positive definite. For the ratio of smallest to larger eigenvalues of K I get the followin $(3.6817381615078046e-16+0j)$. Do you think that is the reason that $c_1$ and $c_2$ differ as this ratio is virtually zero? I'm still puzzeled that numpy doens't throw an error for inverting $K$, although it takes very long. Again thanks for your patience!

Comment: No worries, @math. The ratio you reported indicates $$ is very close to be nonsingular. Compute $\tilde KK$ where $\tilde K$ denotes the numerical approximate of $K^{-1}$ you compute from Python, and see how far the product is from $I$.

Comment: i was a bit busy the last couple of days, mea culpa for the late response! I indeed did calculate $\tilde{K}K$ as well as $K\tilde{K}$. What surprised me the both were not the same. In both cases i didn't fully achieve a identity matrix. In the latter case I got diagonal elements with $10^-3$ deviation form $1$. While for the other I encountered a much larger deviation, i.e. a diagonal element was close to 1000! It seems a bit strange...I will try form scratch to see that there are no typos in the code...thanks again for you help / patience. vey much appreciated it!

Comment: No worries. There was an important typo in my last comment. I meant to say "The ratio you reported indicates $K$ is very close to be **singular**" rather than nonsingular. That predicts the strangeness you see.

Comment: Yes I did! Sorry for the late response. With all the festive season going on I just check in occasionally. Makes sense now. happy new year and many thanks again for your patience and helpè